# Apache mod_rewrite not working

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I installed Apache through its windows installer and then PHP and MySQL too. Wordpress is working fine on this setup so it means the basic setup required is working fine.

But somehow mod_rewriting is not working even though i have uncommented the LoadModule.....mod_rewrite from httpd.conf.

whenever i go to some permalink on my localhost I just get a 404 (browser based, not wordpress based).

Please suggest the required changes that i need to do.

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: Did you have a look in your error_log?

Comment: @greg yes i did. but radius solved the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive doesn't allow the .htaccess file of wordpress to be used. So double check that `AllowOverride FileInfo` is enable for your wordpress directory.

---

For the future when you ask these sorts of questions please include :

- any rewrite configuration you've done in apache
- the content of the .htaccess file in the root directory of wordpress
- apache version

Comment: 1.I haven't done any rewrite config, i just enabled permalinks through wordpress.
2.contents are what wordpress makes them by default,
3.apache 2.2.13
there you go!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your wordpress .htaccess file isn't being used by apache. Inside your httpd.conf file replace "Override None" with "Override All".

Comment: AllowOverride FileInfo should be enough, see my answer on serverfault : http://serverfault.com/questions/54700/apache-modrewrite-not-working/54702#54702